# how to instantiate server side secure renegotiation

Tags: ssl, apache2

Can anyone please tell me about "how to enable secure renegotiation in apache2"? Specific commands or entries that are to be added in httpd.con or ssl.conf files.

My main motive is to instantiate Server side renegotiation. Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a silly idea as it opens your server up to attack. This would never be done in a business environment.

mod_ssl has an [option](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslinsecurerenegotiation) but they make it very clear that it can make your server vulnerable.

Comment: Actually, there is SLB in between the Client and Server. So, I am testing the SLB here.